# How to get input for each varible in list using loop in python

Tags: python

I want it to ask "enter not green cost for Jan" and then after input ask for Feb and so on. I could so it one by 1 but is there a way to make it reiterate the question with a loop while going onto the next month each time?

```
months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
def main():
    get_notgreen()

def get_notgreen():
    not_green = [] * 12
    for x in range(1,12):
        not_green.append(input(f'Enter not green cost for {months[0]}:'))
        
        print(not_green)

main()
```

Comment: Change your loop to  `for month in months:` and change `months[0]` for `month`

Comment: What do you expect `[] * 12` to do? `not_green = []` is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of doing it, but the best would be something like this:

```py
months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']

def get_notgreen():
    return [input(f'Enter not green cost for {month}:') for month in months]

def main():
    print(get_notgreen())

main()
```

However, what you thought you were writing, which is less good, was this:

```py
months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']

def main():
    get_notgreen()

def get_notgreen():
    not_green = []
    for x in range(12):
        not_green.append(input(f'Enter not green cost for {months[x]}:'))
        
    print(not_green)

main()
```